# How To Delete Rows From Temp Table With EntityDelete In CFSCRIPT

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion-10, cfml

If I have an array of entities loaded from a temp relation using `ORMExecuteQuery()`, how can I use `EntityDelete()` to delete all entities.

I have tried `EntityDelete( tempArr )` but it does not work. However, I am able to iterate through the array and add each entity with additional info into a new final relation.

Here is my `cfscript` code:

```
tempArr = ORMExecuteQuery( "FROM TEMP WHERE CartID=#FORM.CartID#" );
transaction {
    for( i=1; i LTE ArrayLen(tempArr); i=i+1 ) {
        reg = EntityNew( "register" );
        reg.setFirstName( tempArr[i].getFirstName() );
        ........
        EntitySave( reg );
        ORMFlush();
    }
    EntityDelete( tempArr );//<<== THIS IS NOT DELETING THE ENTITIES
}
```

Error:

```
- Object passed is not a valid entity.
```

Comment: I've not really used CF's Hibernate wrapper much beyond proof-of-concept, but having googled how to do this in HQL, is it not just a matter of prepending `DELETE ` to your existing HQL statement? Ref: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

Comment: Thanks so much @AdamCameron. That's a very helpful article and I am sure I'll be using some ideas from that in my development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EntityDelete( tempArr[i] );` at the end of the for-loop.

```
tempArr = ORMExecuteQuery( "FROM TEMP WHERE CartID=#FORM.CartID#" );
transaction {
    for( i=1; i LTE ArrayLen(tempArr); i=i+1 ) {
        reg = EntityNew( "register" );
        reg.setFirstName( tempArr[i].getFirstName() );
        ........
        EntitySave( reg );
        ORMFlush();
        EntityDelete( tempArr[i] );//<<== THIS WORKS!!
    }
}
```